# EditText Values in range

Tags: android

I would like to enter the values in a range like 1-60. The `EditText` shouldn't accept values like 61,62..., or 0,-1,-2...

How can we give the range 1-60 to `EditText` in android?
I have done in main.xml as

```
 <EditText android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:id="@+id/editText1" 
    android:layout_width="160dip" 
    android:inputType="number">
    </EditText>
```

Comment: After reading this question a few times, it's unclear whether you are looking to validate and edit the input while the user is typing, or after they exit the field.  You have two answers below that address both of these cases.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can assign a `TextWatcher` to your `EditText` and listen for text changes there, for example:

```
public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
   try {
     int val = Integer.parseInt(s.toString());
     if(val > 60) {
        s.replace(0, s.length(), "60", 0, 2);
     } else if(val < 1) {
        s.replace(0, s.length(), "1", 0, 1);
     }
   } catch (NumberFormatException ex) {
      // Do something
   }
}
```

As mentioned by Devunwired, notice that calls to `s.replace()` will call the TextWatcher again recursively.

It is typical to wrap these changes with a check on a boolean "editing" flag so the recursive calls skip over and simply return while the changes that come from within.

Comment: +1: This is the correct way to handle this, but it should be noted that changes you make here will often call the TextWatcher again recursively.  It is typical to wrap these changes with a check on a boolean "editing" flag so the recursive calls skip over and simply return while the changes come from within.

Answer (score 4):

I have come across a neat solution [here](http://tech.chitgoks.com/2011/06/27/android-set-min-max-value-an-edittext-accepts/):

```
public class InputFilterMinMax implements InputFilter {

private int min, max;

public InputFilterMinMax(int min, int max) {
    this.min = min;
    this.max = max;
}

public InputFilterMinMax(String min, String max) {
    this.min = Integer.parseInt(min);
    this.max = Integer.parseInt(max);
}

@Override
public CharSequence filter(CharSequence source, int start, int end, Spanned dest, int dstart, int dend) {
    try {
        int input = Integer.parseInt(dest.toString() + source.toString());
        if (isInRange(min, max, input))
            return null;
    } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) { }
    return "";
}

private boolean isInRange(int a, int b, int c) {
    return b > a ? c >= a && c <= b : c >= b && c <= a;
}
}
```

And simply apply this filter to an edit text like so:

```
mCentsEditText = (EditText)v.findViewById(R.id.cents_edit_text);
InputFilterMinMax filter = new InputFilterMinMax("0", "99") {};
mCentsEditText.setFilters(new InputFilter[]{filter});
```

Comment: This solution does not work for say a range of 5 to 35, as it will now allow you to input 11, as a single 1 is less than the 5 minimum.

Comment: Still high up on the google search result so wanted to let people know. I worked around it by hard coding a minimum of 0 and using another check on leave to confirm it is correct.

Answer (score 2):

I fixed Daniel Wilson's solution:

```
public class InputFilterMinMax implements InputFilter {

private int min, max;

public InputFilterMinMax(int min, int max) {
    this.min = min;
    this.max = max;
}

public InputFilterMinMax(String min, String max) {
    this.min = Integer.parseInt(min);
    this.max = Integer.parseInt(max);
}

@Override
public CharSequence filter(CharSequence source, int start, int end, Spanned dest, int dstart, int dend) {
    try {
        //The commented line below only works if you append/modify the end of the text (not the beginning or middle)
        //int input = Integer.parseInt(dest.toString() + source.toString());
        //corrected solution below (3lines)
        CharSequence part1 = dest.subSequence(0, dstart);
        CharSequence part2 = dest.subSequence(dend, dest.length());
        int input = Integer.parseInt(part1 + source.toString() + part2);

        if (isInRange(min, max, input))
            return null;
    } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) { }
    return "";
}

private boolean isInRange(int a, int b, int c) {
    return b > a ? c >= a && c <= b : c >= b && c <= a;
}
}
```

Finally add the InputFilter to your EditText control:

```
mCentsEditText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.cents_edit_text);
InputFilterMinMax filter = new InputFilterMinMax("1", "60") {};
mCentsEditText.setFilters(new InputFilter[]{filter});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this..

```
   EditText.setOnEditorActionListener(new OnEditorActionListener()
    {
@Override
public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event)
{
    //add your condtion here.
    return false;
}   
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not use a Seekbar Instead of EditText?
That way, only numbers can be entered and the maximum limit can be specified/modified as and when you need.

```
public class SeekBar1 extends Activity implements SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener {
 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   ..
   mSeekBar = (SeekBar)findViewById(R.id.seekBar);
   mSeekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(this);
   ..
 }
 public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromTouch) {
   //Do your Changes Here
 }
 public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
    //On First Track Touch
 }
 public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
    //On Stop Track Touch
 }
}
```

For numerical Input type values, Seekbar is the best possible UI. Although, the precision on it is questionable.

Answer (score 1):

Very interesting question.

I guess the best way to do this is implementing a new `inputType`, but the [setInputType](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setInputType%28int%29) method receives an int. Nothing to do there :(

In that method doc it says:

> Set the type of the content with a
>   constant as defined for inputType.
>   This will take care of changing the
>   key listener, by calling
>   setKeyListener(KeyListener), to match
>   the given content type.

Excellent, you can provide a `keyListener` with [setKeyListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setKeyListener%28android.text.method.KeyListener%29).

You can extend `android.text.method.DigitsKeyListener` to create your new `keyListener`, avoiding the issue with the `TextWatcher`.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have enough priviledges to comment on Ashok Felix's answer but I'd like to add that I have found some code premitting to display a SeekBar in preferences.

It is very easy to use (I'm not the author). See the SeekBarPreference code by Matthew Wiggins: http://android.hlidskialf.com/blog/code/android-seekbar-preference

Answer (score 1):

This works but not live.

```
editText.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
                try {
                    int val = Integer.parseInt(editText.getText()
                            .toString());
                    if (val > 2000) {
                        editText.setText("");
                    } else if (val < 100) {
                        editText.setText("");
                    }
                } catch (NumberFormatException ex) {
                }
            }
        });
```