# Set only certain numbers in EditText - Android

Tags: android, input, android-edittext

I have an EditText input that I would like to only allow numbers 1 - 28 (int's) to be enterable.  How would I do this?

I looked on the android site in regards to   android:inputType but could not find anything that fits (to customize).

Comment: see this :: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5391394/edittext-values-in-range

Comment: Both comments were great ideas but I just went for a different direction.  I used a hint in the EditText box to guide the user and just validated onClick.  if (x > 28 || x < 1) then { Toast warning and don't submit } else { submit }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should just use a [NumberPicker](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/NumberPicker.html) instead which allows you to specify min and max.

If you want, you can hide the + and - buttons and then the user will only see the EditText and it will meet your requirements.

For the number picker to appear on the screen, you must have called setMinValue/setMaxValue on it.