# Range Validation for EditText in android

Tags: android, validation, android-edittext, range

Can anyone tell me how to validate range of EditText in Android?? I want to limit my value not length.
For example,user will be able to give their weight between 20 to 400Kg only. So,is this possible with xml file? Or any other option for range validation of `EditText`?

Comment: You should add a TextWatcher to the EditText and check the user's input in every call. Is not possible via XML. Just by code. C'mon! It's very simple

Comment: possible duplicate of [EditText Values in range](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5391394/edittext-values-in-range)

Comment: I am a new in android development. so, recently i am not using anything for that. so, i dont know about hoe to validate range in EditText.

Answer (score -1):

```
    EditText etExample= (EditText) getView().findViewById(R.id.etExample);
    etExample.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            String text = s.toString().replaceAll("[^0-9]", "").Trim();
            System.out.println(Integer.valueOf(text) > 400 ? "Whale" : "Not a Whale");
        }
    });
```