# How to add a range in the EditText so that the input will highlight in red when typing if it goes out of range in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-edittext, range, highlight

```
    eOUTPUT_VOLTAGE_L_N_V=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.bb_output_voltage_l_n_v_text);
    eLOAD_CURRENT_A=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.bb_load_current_a_text);
    eALARM_STATUS=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.bb_alarm_status_text);
    eSTATUS=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.bb_status_text);
    eREMARK=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.bb_remark_text);
```

Specifically I want to limit the values to be entered into the edit text by highlighting in red when typing if it goes out of range. For an example I want to input a numerical range like 200v - 400v for the eOUTPUT_VOLTAGE_L_N_V so that the typing text would highlight in red when user typing a out of range value like 600v.

Comment: You have to use `TextWatcher` and set error based on your requirement

Comment: Does this answer your question? [EditText Values in range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5391394/edittext-values-in-range)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  eOUTPUT_VOLTAGE_L_N_V.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
               @Override
               public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

               }

               @Override
               public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

                       if(Integer.parseInt(s.toString()) > 400){
                             eOUTPUT_VOLTAGE_L_N_V.setError("something");
                        }

               }

               @Override
               public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

               }
           });
```

Comment: It will produce **NumberFormatException**

Comment: I think you put integer with some alphabets. You need to split that alphabet before .

Comment: If you put like this 200v. then replace or split 'v' before if(Integer.parseInt(s.toString()) > 400){
                             eOUTPUT_VOLTAGE_L_N_V.setError("something");
                        }

Comment: You can remove alphabet.